# Model to write jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, modeling

I have to create a document that provides a "model" for how to write jQuery plugins for a large site.

For example: all plugins should have:

```
$.fn.somePlugin = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        // Here the plugins does its goal.
    });
};
```

so they respect the fluent model and also they can be called with multiple elements at same time. Some other things I think they should all have are:

- Options getter and setter (like in jQuery-ui)
- Methods (like in jQuery-ui)
- Some way to change default options. Of course this should be done without modifying the plugin file (again, like jQuery-ui).

How would it be your "Model Plugin"? (achieving this and some other things you think necessary in the best possible way).

**Result**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/cr83Y/9/) you can see my plugin template based on all the information I read.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring has some pretty good guidelines

Comment: Are you writing your own library or are you trying to extend the jquery core library?

Comment: I would avoid jQuery plugins as an architecture pattern. It's a really poor pattern. Please use module loaders and modular code instead

Comment: @Incognito I'm trying to create a model to create plugins which extends jquery core.

Comment: @Raynos Could you be more specific or give me some example please?

Comment: @Diego module loader of choice, browserify, requirejs, seajs, modul8, lobrow, curl.js. All those can be used to define modules (`define(name, obj)`) and require modules `var module = require(name)`. You now have modular code and you just write modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jquery docs have a section on plugin authoring:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

and here's the "slides" from ben almans talk on plugin authoring from the boston jquery conference:

https://github.com/cowboy/talks/blob/master/jquery-plugin-authoring.js

and one more link from ben alman about writing plugins.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff696759

Comment: Based on all this links I've build my own template. When I finish testing it I'll publish a link.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use a structure similar to this

```
(function ($, plugin) {
  "use strict";

  $[plugin] = function (options/* params */) {
    var settings;
    settings = $.extend({}, $[plugin].defaultSettings, options);
    //static funciton code here
  };

  $.fn[plugin] = function (options/* params */) {
    this.each(function (index, element) {
      var settings, $this;
      settings = $.extend({}, $.fn[plugin].defaultSettings, options);
      $this = $(this);
      $this.data(plugin+'Settings', settings);
      //chainable function code here
    });
    return this;
  };

  $[plugin].defaultSettings = {
    'foo': 'bar'
  };

  $.fn[plugin].defaultSettings = {
    'fizz': 'buzz'
  };

  $(function(){
    //document.ready initialization code here
  });
}(jQuery, 'foo'));
```

I don't usually bother with the `plugin` parameter, but it could be useful for generalizing the name of a plugin

For event shortcuts, I'll use:

```
$.each('foo bar baz'.split(' '), function(i, name) {
  $.fn[name] = function(data,fn){
    if (fn == null) {
      fn = data;
      data = null;
    }
    return arguments.length > 0 ?
      this.bind(name, data, fn) :
      this.trigger(name);
  };
});
```

Which will produce `.foo()`, `.bar()`, `.baz()` all as shortcuts for binding/triggering the `'foo'`, `'bar'`, and `'baz'` events.

Comment: Note that all these sections are optional. It's perfectly valid to not have any document.ready or static code

Comment: This doesn't achieve all the things I asked for. i e How would you get or set an option after the plugin was called?

Comment: @Diego, beggars can't be choosers :-p how you handle parameters is up to you. You'll need a thorough understanding of each different method signature that you plan on supporting, and will need to do type checking to see if the correct parameters were provided.

Comment: @Diego, I highly recommend looking over the [jQuery-UI widget factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget-factory). If you're making a larger widget it can significantly simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following template for a LONG time now and it seems to do everything needed as well as provide for traditional jQuery scripting, such as: `$.myPlugin("element", {options})`, `$.myPlugin({options}, callback)`, or '$("element").myPlugin();

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.myExample) { // check your plugin namespace does not already exist
        $.extend({  //  this will allow you to add your plugin to the jQuery lib
            myExample: function(elm, command, args) {
                //  keep in mind, right here you might want to do a class or data check to determine which direction this call is going
                //  for example, upon init the plugin on an element you may add the plugin name as a class, 
                //      this way, when it's recalled, you can see it alrady has that class and might be calling a command,
                //          thus make an if statemnt to push the process through
                return elm.each(function(index){
                    // do work to each element as its passed through
                    // be sure to use something like
                    //    return elm.each(function(e) { dor work });
                    // as your final statement in order to maintain "chainability"
                });
            }
        });
        $.fn.extend({   //  this gives the chainability functionality seen with $ funcs like: $("#eleID").css("color", "red") <--returns original element object
            myExample: function(command) {
                return $.myExample($(this), command, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            }
        });
        $.myExample.props = {   //  Here you can establish specific properties to your plugin, prehaps even make them "Over-writable"
            key1: "value",
            key2: "value"
        };
        $.myExample.methods = { //  Here you can establish specific methods/functions for your plguin to carry out and maintain your namespace as well
            key1: function(param) {
                /*  do work */
            },
            key2: function(param) {
                /*  do work */
            }
        };
        //  This next part is not seen in many plugins but useful depending on what you're creating
        $.myExample.init = function(param) {    //  If you have an initialize method to apply, namespace it in here and calll on initializing your plugin
            var key = "value",
                key2 = {
                    subKey: "value"
                };
                /*
                /  run any number of initializing functions here
                /  I prefer to make my param a value that can be a
                /   string with a possible object
                /   the string for holding a base configuration
                /   the object for any change in properties or base values for that config
                */
        };
        $.myExample.defaults = {    //  establish base properties here that can be over-written via .props, but their values should never truly change
            key1: "value",
            key2: {
                prop1: {
                    subKey1: "value",
                    subKey2: "value"
                },
                prop2: {
                    subKey1: "value"
                }
            },
            key3: function(param) {

            }
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```